# Bootstrap make blue lines around section on click

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Well, this problem is only in google chrome on both desktop and mobile.
I added picture where u can clearly see the problem.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Blue line appears when i click on the section or when i click on the item in menu (contact, portfolio....).

Example of my code:

```
<section class="ip_fifth_block" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <h1 class="ip_services_heading" style="margin-bottom:0">Kontakt</h1>
        </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <p class="ip_heading_under">Zanechajte nám Váš odkaz, pripomienku, objednávku.</p>
        </div>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <form>
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-6 ip_forminfo">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Meno a priezvisko"><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Tel. číslo"><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 ip_forminfo">
                                     <textarea placeholder="Vaša správa"></textarea>

                                    <input type="submit" value="Odoslať">

                                </div>
                            </div>   

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>


    <div id="map"></div>


</section>
```

Comment: lol at those unidentified people in image2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your section has a `tabindex` attribute which define the tab order when the <kbd>tab</kbd> key is pressed to navigate or you can say focused and focused elements has a browser default outline. So all you need to do is set the outline value to `none`

```css
[tabindex] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="1">foobar</p>
```